# I cannot get electron to access my threeJS folder

Tags: javascript, electron

[Tech stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA4Zg.png)

[javascript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eeQG.png)

ThreeJS always fails when combined with electron for me.
It can't find the libraries. I wonder if my paths are wrong in some way. I tried using a absolute path.

The browser displays, it just won't have anything to do with three.
Three exists inside node_modules. I installed three using npm.
//import * as THREE from 'node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';

[Three is stored locally inside node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrdUB.png)

[Index.html hates the import three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39XXt.png)

[Browser displays in electron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0PCT.png)

[index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqyWI.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>


<div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a>webgl</div>
<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/three/build/three.module.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    //import * as THREE from 'node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
    //import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

//import * as THREE from 'three';
//import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
//C:\Users\HP\Desktop\threeJS\three.js-master
//C:\Users\HP\Desktop\threeJS\three.js-master\three.js
//import * as THREE from '/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
// import * as THREE from '/node_modules/three';
// import { Mesh } from 'three';
// import {OrbitControls} from "/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";


const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector('#background_canvas'),
});

//const color3 = new THREE.Color("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
//const color4 = new THREE.Color("rgb(0%, 50%, 50%)");
//Note the lack of CamelCase in the name
//const color5 = new THREE.Color( 'skyblue' );

//renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xffffff, 1.0));

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.position.setZ(30);
camera.position.setX(-3);

//renderer.render(scene, camera);

//const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(10, 3, 16, 100);
//const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xff6347, wireframe: true });
//const torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

// https://blog.logrocket.com/three-js-geometries-and-materials/ 
// The first arg is the radius of the cylinder’s top; the second is the radius of the bottom. 
// The third argument represents the height of the cylinder.
// We can set the number of edges connecting the top and bottom faces down the curved surface. 
// This is called the radiusSegments, and it goes in as the fourth arg. The default value is 8.
// We can also set the number of rings of faces around the curved surface. This is called heightSegments. 
// It goes as the fifth argument with a default value of 1.
// You can determine whether the ends of the cylinder are open or closed. 
// It’s a boolean: true makes it open

const cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(15, 15, 15, 7, 5, false);
//we changed from MeshBasicMaterial that does NOT require a lightsource to MeshStandardMaterial, that does.
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xffff00, wireframe: false});
const meshedSelector = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderGeometry, material);

//const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
//pointLight.position.set(5,10,10);

const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
//scene.add(pointLight, ambientLight);
scene.add(directionalLight);

//const lightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pointLight);
const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(200,50);
//scene.add(lightHelper,gridHelper);
scene.add(gridHelper);

//This listens to dom events on the mouse and updates the screen accordingly
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

//scene.add(torus);
scene.add(meshedSelector)

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  //torus.rotation.x += 0.01;
  //torus.rotation.y += 0.005;
  //torus.rotation.z += 0.01;

  meshedSelector.rotation.x += 0.01;
  meshedSelector.y += 0.005;
  meshedSelector.z += 0.01;

  cylinderGeometry.computeVertexNormals();

  controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
</script>

</body>
</html>
<!-- import * as THREE from 'three'; -->
<!-- https://blog.arashtad.com/blog/how-to-use-orbit-controls-a-complete-guide/
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Mesh } from 'three';  -->

<!-- <script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/": "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/"
        }
    }
</script> -->

<!-- import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { RGBELoader } from "three/addons/loaders/RGBELoader.js";
import { GUI } from "three/addons/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js"; -->

<!-- import * as THREE from '/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
import { Mesh } from 'three';
import {OrbitControls} from "/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"; -->

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, innerWidth / innerHeight , 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
     antialias : true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
//creating a sphere
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 50, 50);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
     color:0x3268F8
});
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
scene.add(sphere);
camera.position.z = 15;
function animate(){
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     renderer.render(scene,camera);
     sphere.rotation.y += 0.003;
}
animate();


<!-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>threeJS</title>
        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                color: #cccccc;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;

                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            a {

                color: #0080ff;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container"></div>
        <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> webgl - buffergeometry - uint</div>
        <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/three.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var mesh;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

                //

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 27, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3500 );
                camera.position.z = 2750;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x050505, 2000, 3500 );

                //

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 ) );

                var light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
                light1.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                scene.add( light1 );

                var light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.5 );
                light2.position.set( 0, -1, 0 );
                scene.add( light2 );

                //

                var triangles = 160000;

                var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();



                var indices = new Uint32Array( triangles * 3 );

                for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; i ++ ) {

                    indices[ i ] = i;

                }

                var positions = new Float32Array( triangles * 3 * 3 );
                var normals = new Float32Array( triangles * 3 * 3 );
                var colors = new Float32Array( triangles * 3 * 3 );

                var color = new THREE.Color();

                var n = 800, n2 = n/2;  // triangles spread in the cube
                var d = 12, d2 = d/2;   // individual triangle size

                var pA = new THREE.Vector3();
                var pB = new THREE.Vector3();
                var pC = new THREE.Vector3();

                var cb = new THREE.Vector3();
                var ab = new THREE.Vector3();

                for ( var i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 9 ) {

                    // positions

                    var x = Math.random() * n - n2;
                    var y = Math.random() * n - n2;
                    var z = Math.random() * n - n2;

                    var ax = x + Math.random() * d - d2;
                    var ay = y + Math.random() * d - d2;
                    var az = z + Math.random() * d - d2;

                    var bx = x + Math.random() * d - d2;
                    var by = y + Math.random() * d - d2;
                    var bz = z + Math.random() * d - d2;

                    var cx = x + Math.random() * d - d2;
                    var cy = y + Math.random() * d - d2;
                    var cz = z + Math.random() * d - d2;

                    positions[ i ]     = ax;
                    positions[ i + 1 ] = ay;
                    positions[ i + 2 ] = az;

                    positions[ i + 3 ] = bx;
                    positions[ i + 4 ] = by;
                    positions[ i + 5 ] = bz;

                    positions[ i + 6 ] = cx;
                    positions[ i + 7 ] = cy;
                    positions[ i + 8 ] = cz;

                    // flat face normals

                    pA.set( ax, ay, az );
                    pB.set( bx, by, bz );
                    pC.set( cx, cy, cz );

                    cb.subVectors( pC, pB );
                    ab.subVectors( pA, pB );
                    cb.cross( ab );

                    cb.normalize();

                    var nx = cb.x;
                    var ny = cb.y;
                    var nz = cb.z;

                    normals[ i ]     = nx;
                    normals[ i + 1 ] = ny;
                    normals[ i + 2 ] = nz;

                    normals[ i + 3 ] = nx;
                    normals[ i + 4 ] = ny;
                    normals[ i + 5 ] = nz;

                    normals[ i + 6 ] = nx;
                    normals[ i + 7 ] = ny;
                    normals[ i + 8 ] = nz;

                    // colors

                    var vx = ( x / n ) + 0.5;
                    var vy = ( y / n ) + 0.5;
                    var vz = ( z / n ) + 0.5;

                    color.setRGB( vx, vy, vz );

                    colors[ i ]     = color.r;
                    colors[ i + 1 ] = color.g;
                    colors[ i + 2 ] = color.b;

                    colors[ i + 3 ] = color.r;
                    colors[ i + 4 ] = color.g;
                    colors[ i + 5 ] = color.b;

                    colors[ i + 6 ] = color.r;
                    colors[ i + 7 ] = color.g;
                    colors[ i + 8 ] = color.b;

                }

                geometry.addAttribute( 'index', new THREE.BufferAttribute( indices, 1 ) );
                geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
                geometry.addAttribute( 'normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );
                geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );

                geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    color: 0xaaaaaa, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 250,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
                } );

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( mesh );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false, alpha : true } );
                renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
                // renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                // renderer.gammaInput = true;
                // renderer.gammaOutput = true;

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();

            }

            function render() {

                var time = Date.now() * 0.001;

                mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.25;
                mesh.rotation.y = time * 0.5;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script> -->
```

package.json file:

```html
{
  "name": "sat_3_9_2024",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "Electron ThreeJs Viewer",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "comment1": "Start is the file that runs from cmd line using npm",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "author": "Heather M",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-fuses": "^7.3.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-vite": "^7.3.0",
    "electron": "^29.1.1",
    "vite": "^5.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "three": "^0.162.0",
    "three-orbit-controls": "^82.1.0",
    "tsx": "^4.7.1"
  }
}
```